# What is the use of getchar()?

Tags: c++, c, getchar

Where do we use `getchar()` instead of `scanf()` or `cin` ? 
Also, shouldn't the syntax of `getchar()` be `char getchar()` instead of `int getchar()`? Since we are reading in character type input.

Comment: Reading [some documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) should answer the second question.

Comment: `cin` isn't in C, it's specific to C++. `getchar` is about as simple as you can get; `scanf` might use `getchar` internally. It returns `int` because it may return `EOF`, which is outside of the character range.

Comment: `getchar` returns `int` because `EOF` is outside the range of `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C and C++ are different languages; `getchar` exists in C whereas `cin` (which inherently depends on classes) does not.  Also `scanf` is very slow compared to `getchar` because `scanf` has to read through a lot more data and do a lot more processing than `getchar` does.

Another reason for having `getchar` is that it is used in while loops like this

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
  /* do some stuff here */
}
```

so that you can keep reading characters until you specifically reach `EOF` (or any other character you choose).

By the way, `EOF` is an `int` (because it isn't a valid character that can be read) which is why `getchar` has to return an `int`.

Comment: Good answer, but I would change "you can keep reading lines" to "you can keep reading characters"

Comment: Who thinks I should make this answer comunity wiki?

Comment: The answer is given many times in the comments so I made this community wiki.

Comment: Agree to EOF is an int, so getchar is int getchar(); but what about when we enter an character? Is it taking the ASCII value and then converting it to character or there is an implicit conversion which  would be close to impossible.

Comment: Even if I take char getchar() , I can work my way out by taking EOF as 'r', so when a user type r, he comes out of while loop.So, int is not mandatory to be prefixed?